# ADO.NET - Bad Practice?

Tags: ado.net

I was reading an article in MSDN several months ago and have recently started using the following snippet to execute ADO.NET code, but I get the feeling it could be bad. Am I over reacting or is it perfectly acceptable?

```
private void Execute(Action<SqlConnection> action)
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        action.Invoke(conn);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
            try {
                conn.Close();
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }
}

public bool GetSomethingById() {
    SomeThing aSomething = null
    bool valid = false;
    Execute(conn =>
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = ....
            ...
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ...
            aSomething = new SomeThing(Convert.ToString(reader["aDbField"]));
        }
    });
    return aSomething;
}
```

Comment: What does this do that the `using` statement doesn't already do, except for passing in the connection string for you?

Answer (score 8):

What is the point of doing that when you can do this?

```
public SomeThing GetSomethingById(int id) 
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand()) 
        {
            // prepare command
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                // read fields
                return new SomeThing(data);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

You can promote code reuse by doing something like this.

```
public static void ExecuteToReader(string connectionString, string commandText, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> parameters, Action<IDataReader> action) 
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand()) 
        {
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            foreach (var pair in parameters) 
            {
                var parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
                parameter.ParameterName = pair.Key; 
                parameter.Value = pair.Value; 
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                action(rdr);
            }
        } 
    }    
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
//At the top create an alias
using DbParams = Dictionary<string, object>;

ExecuteToReader(
    connectionString, 
    commandText, 
    new DbParams() { { "key1", 1 }, { "key2", 2 } }),
    reader => 
    {
        // ...
        // No need to dispose
    }
)
```

Comment: What happens if an exception occurs? Would I be wrong in thinking the connection will be left hanging and not closed?

Comment: @Echilon - Nope, the using statement will for your purposes close the connection. Technically it will remain open because of connection pooling.

Comment: I wouldn't use a Dictionary for this, use the DBParameter class instead. Adding - params DBParameter[] parameters - to the end of the method definition is a nice approach.

Comment: @Zyphrax - but then you have to pass the params like this: `new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "key1", Value = 1 }` which I feel is really verbose.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is indeed a bad practice, since you're creating and opening a new database-connection for every statement that you execute.

Why is it bad:

- performance wise (although connection pooling helps decrease the performance hit): you should open your connection, execute the statements that have to be executed, and close the connection when you don't know when the next statement will be executed.
- but certainly context-wise.  I mean:  how will you handle transactions ? Where are your transaction boundaries ?  Your application-layer knows when a transaction has to be started and committed, but you're unable to span multiple statements into the same sql-transaction with this way of working.

Comment: I was going to say something to this effect. While it looks like it is possible to execute multiple statements inside a single action I can see it being used to generate results for very specific actions resulting in a lot of unnecessary disconnect/connect behaviors.

Comment: He is not opening and closing a database connection for every statement. ADO.NET uses a connection pool. Calling `connection.Close` **doesn't** close the underlying database connection but it returns it to the connection pool for reuse (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @Darin: that's what I'm saying.  But, I semantically, it is still wrong.

Comment: You write: `you're creating and opening a new database-connection for every statement that you execute`. This statement is wrong. Please read the Remarks section of the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's acceptable. I've created a SqlUtilities class two years ago that had a similar method. You can take it one step further if you like.

**EDIT:** Couldn't find the code, but I typed a small example (probably with many syntax errors ;))

**SQLUtilities**

```
public delegate T CreateMethod<T> (SqlDataReader reader);
public static T CreateEntity<T>(string query, CreateMethod<T> createMethod, params SqlParameter[] parameters) {
   // Open the Sql connection
   // Create a Sql command with the query/sp and parameters
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   return createMethod(reader);
   // Probably some finally statements or using-closures etc. etc.
}
```

**Calling code**

```
private SomeThing Create(SqlDataReader reader) {
    SomeThing something = new SomeThing();
    something.ID = Convert.ToIn32(reader["ID"]);
    ...
    return something;
}

public SomeThing GetSomeThingByID (int id) {
    return SqlUtilities.CreateEntity<SomeThing> ("something_getbyid", Create, ....);
}
```

Of course you could use a lambda expression instead of the Create method, and you could easily make a CreateCollection method and reuse the existing Create method.

However if this is a new project. Check out LINQ to entities. Is far easier and flexible than ADO.Net.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very reasonable approach to use.

By wrapping your connection logic into a method which takes an `Action<SqlConnection>`, you're helping prevent duplicated code and the potential for introduced error.  Since we can now use lambdas, this becomes an easy, safe way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, In my opinion check what you do before going through it.Something that is working doesn't mean it is best and good programming practice.Check out and find a concrete example and benefit of using it.But if you are considering using for big projects it would be nice using frameworks like NHibernate.Because there are a lot projects even frameworks developed based on it,like http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/.